# Bootstrap v3.3.0 Columns Too Wide

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been really frustrated over the issue, searched many options, found none to work, and do not have the heart to ponder over it further.

The website in question is https://flix-c9-airbusai342.c9.io/.

Here, I'm having issues with the columns being too wide in mobile. Yes, they are properly stacking, however, not sure what's causing it to be too wide.

Below is a direct snippet of the code of the area in question. The class .stats is only`background-color: #D8D8D8;` for changing background color.

```
<section class="stats">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-4" align="center">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x turquoise"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-code fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
            <h2>Professional Coding</h2>
            <span class="text-muted"><p>A team of experienced web developers are ready to give you the best quality code available to be provded for you. <b>Each</b> and <b>every</b> time.</p></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" align="center">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x turquoise"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-bolt fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
            <h2>Dedicated Team</h2>
            <span class="text-muted"><p>Nothing's perfect. Even us. Thus, our dedicated team is ready to help you whenever you need it, even if it means sacrificing leasure time.</p></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" align="center">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x turquoise"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
            </span>
            <h2>Mobile compatible</h2>
            <span class="text-muted"><p>We know the new trends of websites. Meeting popular demand, our websites by default look great on any device across. Even this website.</p></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I openly allow you to view the page source of the website.

Thank you for any assistance; my dull mind is suffering. :)

Comment: .row not .row-fluid -- that does not exist in bootstrap 3 and will mess up the grid.

Comment: also, don't use align="center" that will also mess up your layout. That's something I haven't seen since early 2000s. Use "text-center" on the col-md-4. class="col-md-4 text-center"

Comment: Also see the answer, you have a min-width on your .section

Comment: Looks like clearly my section was screwed up. Guess I didn't see that.

Comment: I only used the align="center" because that was what I was taught... Whoops!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *min-width of 960px* on your `.section`

Removing that will solve a lot of things. If you do not want your content to stretch to the full width of the window, use a `max-width: 960px;` instead. Otherwise, just remove the *min-width of 960px*

Remove `.row-fluid` and use `.row`.

Remove `align="center"` that's old stuff

Use `.text-center` on the parent of the stuff you want centered (provided it's inline or inline-block elements)

Use `.center-block` on any block elements (like an `.img-responsive`).

Comment: OP: Always read the documentation and play with the examples. You didn't read the docs.

Comment: Looks like I have to wait one minute, but let me say, AMAZING HELP, and then mark as answer. However, thank you! Looks like I'm still the new guy on the block with this stuff, but thank you for teaching me something. :)